# Divide list of values in dictionary by list of values in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to take a dictionary with list values and divide each element in that list by the corresponding element in another dictionary list values.

For example, if you have these two dictionaries where the keys of the dictionaries do not match,

```
dict1={"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9]}
dict2={"D": [10,20,30], "B":[40,50,60], "C":[70,80,90]}
```

I'd like to iterate through the list elements and divide the elements of the list, such that the output is something like this,

```
new_dict={"A": [1/10, 2/20, 3/30], "B":[4/40, 5/50, 6/60], "C": [7/70, 8/80, 9/90]}
```

I've tried something like this, but get am getting held up with figuring out how to get into the lists.

```
new_dict={}
for key, value in dict1:
       new_dict={key: [i/j for i, j in zip(value, dict2.values()]}
new_dict
```

Thank you so much for any and all help!

Comment: Why is A being divided by D?

Comment: I'd like to keep the keys of dict1 for the new_dict, but the keys of dict2 do not match that of dict1.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to build the resulting dictionary, and a list comprehension to build the values of that dictionary:

```
>>> dict1
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
>>> dict2
{'A': [10, 20, 30], 'B': [40, 50, 60], 'C': [70, 80, 90]}
>>> res = {key: [x1/x2 for (x1,x2) in zip(dict1[key],dict2[key])] for key in dict2}
>>> res
{'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'B': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'C': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}
```

If they keys don't match and you are going only off the ordering of the keys (which I don't recommend), then you can zip the keys of the first dictionary and the values of the second, then operate on that:

```
>>> dict1={"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9]}
>>> dict2={"D": [10,20,30], "B":[40,50,60], "C":[70,80,90]}
>>> res = {k: [x1/x2 for (x1,x2) in zip(dict1[k],v2)] for (k,v2) in zip(
...         dict1.keys(), dict2.values())}
>>> res
{'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'B': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'C': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}
```

Comment: what if the keys of dict2 do not match that of dict1?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension is what you are looking for:

```
dict1={"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6], "C":[7,8,9]}
dict2={"A": [10,20,30], "B":[40,50,60], "C":[70,80,90]}
```

```
new_dict={key: [i/j for i, j in zip(dict1[key], dict2[key])] for key in dict1}
```

Output:

```
{'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'B': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'C': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if the keys of dict1 and dict2 are not the same?